# JPA Spring CrudRepository TransientObjectException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to manage Persons, Teams and their Membership with Spring Data JPA. 
The following test (whenAddingANewTeamTroughPerson)

1. passes when I use `entityManager.persist(alex);`
2. throws an exception if I use `personRepository.save(alex);`

Why? In the latter case I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: hello.data.model.Person; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: hello.data.model.Person
```

It behaves as CASCADE is not set properely. But it must be correct, since it works with the entityManager.

PersonRepositoryTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class PersonRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TeamRepository teamRepository;

    @Test
    public void whenFindOne_thenReturnPerson() {
        // given
        Person alex = new Person("alex");
        entityManager.persist(alex);
        entityManager.flush();

        // when
        Person found = personRepository.findOne(alex.getId());

        // then
        assertThat(found.getName(), equalToIgnoringWhiteSpace(alex.getName()));
    }

    @Test
    public void whenAddingANewTeamTroughPerson_thenNoException() {
        // given
        Person alex = new Person("alex");
        Team t = new Team("team");
        alex.addTeam(t, "integrationTest", new Date());
        personRepository.save(alex);
        //entityManager.persist(alex);

        // when
        Person found = personRepository.findOne(alex.getId());

        // then
        assertThat(found.getTeams().size(), is(1));
    }

}
```

PersonRepository:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer> {}
```

Person:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Person.class);
    private final IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "id");
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
    private Set<PersonTeam> personTeams = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    private ListProperty<Team> teams = new SimpleListProperty<>(this, "teams", FXCollections.observableArrayList());

    public Person(String s) {
        this.name.set(s);
    }

    public Person() {}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }
    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }
    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.person", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<PersonTeam> getPersonTeams() {
        return personTeams;
    }

    public void setPersonTeams(Set<PersonTeam> personTeams) {
        this.personTeams = personTeams;
        teams.setAll(personTeams.stream().map(PersonTeam::getTeam).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Person person = (Person) o;

        if (getId() != null ? !getId().equals(person.getId()) : person.getId() != null) return false;
        if (getName() != null ? !getName().equals(person.getName()) : person.getName() != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (getName() != null ? getName().hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an Observable List that must remain unchanged.
     * Unfortunately there is no RO Observable List Interface to refer to.
     */
    @Transient
    public ObservableList<Team> getTeams() {
        return teams.get();
    }

    @Transient
    public ReadOnlyListProperty<Team> teamsProperty() {
        return teams;
    }

    public void addTeam(Team team, String createdBy, Date createdDate) {
        final PersonTeam personTeam = new PersonTeam(this, team);
        personTeam.setCreatedBy(createdBy);
        personTeam.setCreatedDate(createdDate);
        if( !personTeams.add(personTeam) ) {
            LOG.error("Failed to add personTeam " + personTeam + " to collection personTeams " + personTeams);
        }
        if( !team.getPersonTeams().add( personTeam ) ) {
            LOG.error("Failed to add personTeam " + personTeam + " to collection team.getPersonTeams " + team.getPersonTeams());
        }
        teams.setAll(personTeams.stream().map(PersonTeam::getTeam).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    public void removeTeam(Team team) {
        PersonTeam personTeam = new PersonTeam( this, team );
        team.getPersonTeams().remove( personTeam );
        personTeams.removeIf( pt -> pt.getTeam() == team );
        personTeam.setPerson( null );
        personTeam.setTeam( null );
        teams.setAll(personTeams.stream().map(PersonTeam::getTeam).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    /*
      The method is not intended to be used in the GUI.
      Use the {@link GUIRepresentable} interface instead.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name.getValue();
    }

}
```

PersonTeam:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person_team")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.person",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.team",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID")) })
public class PersonTeam implements java.io.Serializable {

    private PersonTeamPk pk = new PersonTeamPk();
    private Date createdDate;
    private String createdBy;

    public PersonTeam() {
    }

    public PersonTeam(Person person, Team team) {
        this.pk.setPerson(person);
        this.pk.setTeam(team);
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public PersonTeamPk getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(PersonTeamPk pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Transient
    public Person getPerson() {
        return getPk().getPerson();
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        getPk().setPerson(person);
    }

    @Transient
    public Team getTeam() {
        return getPk().getTeam();
    }

    public void setTeam(Team team) {
        getPk().setTeam(team);
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return this.createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return this.createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        PersonTeam that = (PersonTeam) o;

        if (getPk() != null ? !getPk().equals(that.getPk())
            : that.getPk() != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return (getPk() != null ? getPk().hashCode() : 0);
    }

}
```

PersonTeamPk:

```
@Embeddable
public class PersonTeamPk implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Person person;
    private Team team;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Team getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setTeam(Team team) {
        this.team = team;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        PersonTeamPk that = (PersonTeamPk) o;

        if (person != null ? !person.equals(that.person) : that.person != null) return false;
        if (team != null ? !team.equals(that.team) : that.team != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        result = (person != null ? person.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (team != null ? team.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Team:

```
@Entity
public class Team implements Serializable, Comparable<Team>  {
    private final IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "id");
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
    private Set<PersonTeam> personTeams = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public Team(String s) {
        this.name.set(s);
    }

    public Team() {}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }
    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }
    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.team", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<PersonTeam> getPersonTeams() {
        return personTeams;
    }

    public void setPersonTeams(Set<PersonTeam> personTeams) {
        this.personTeams = personTeams;
    }

    public static Callback<Team, Observable[]> extractor() {
        return (Team p) -> new Observable[]{p.nameProperty()};
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Team team = (Team) o;

        if (getId() != null ? !getId().equals(team.getId()) : team.getId() != null) return false;
        if (getName() != null ? !getName().equals(team.getName()) : team.getName() != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (getName() != null ? getName().hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Team o) {
        return Integer.compare(getId(), o.getId());
    }
}
```